# What exactly causes very bright sources, such as supernovae, to appear as large circles in photographs?

Tags: photography, hubble-telescope, instruments

Consider images such as those in https://hubblesite.org/contents/news-releases/2021/news-2021-007, which show bright supernovae embedded in their host galaxies. No matter which telescope and which detector were used to capture the image, the supernova invariably appears as a comparatively large bright disk. Foreground stars also form disks if they are bright enough, but very much smaller ones.

Which effects exactly cause this effect? Is charge bleed-over between pixels really still an issue with modern detectors? Or is this due to imperfections in the optical components?

And, a related question, is the apparent size of the bright object's disk strictly proportional to brightness?

[image]

> AUTHOR: NASA, ESA, Ryan Foley (UC Santa Cruz)
>
> IMAGE PROCESSING: Joseph DePasquale (STScI)
>
> Public domain

Comment: Does the disc size in the image differ from the reported size of the supernova?   Have you checked whether there's a cloud of gas/dust reflecting the optical-band output of the supernova proper?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is clearly due to the point-spread function for unresolved sources (the supernova is unresoved, and not nearly enough time has passed for any significant reflection by the local environment).

Comment: The image info in the link says (trimming for size) "These images are a composite of separate archival exposures acquired by the WFPC2 instrument on (HST) and more recent ground-based optical data from the Lick Observatory. Several filters were used to sample narrow wavelength ranges. In this case, the assigned colors are: Blue: LCO/B, Green: LCO/V, Orange: LCO/r, Red: LCO/i, Luminosity: HST/F606W". So if the recent ground-based SN image has been resampled onto the higher resolution HST images, its larger pixels and atmosphere-affected image *will* appear as a larger disk.